# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin align editviews on their left edge

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to align all the editview's in the layout below on their left edge.  The top one and the bottom one align fine because they're basically the same.  The middle one (middle initial) aligns on the right edge with the other editviews.  How can I align them on their left edge?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
 <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >
         <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:text="First Name" />
             />
         <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:text="First Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="133.5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="230dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:text="Middle Initial" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="68.5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft = "10dp"
            android:maxLength = "1"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:id="@+id/mi"
            android:text="M" />
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >
         <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:text="Last Name" />
             />
         <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:text="Last Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have added `android:layout_marginRight="230dp"` and by removing the `layout_weight` you can achieve proper alignment.

Use the below:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="First Name" />
        />
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/first_name"
                android:text="First Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Middle Initial" />
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength = "1"
                android:id="@+id/mi"
                android:text="M" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Last Name" />
        />
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/last_name"
                android:text="Last Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You should start using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/), it has better performance and also do drag and drop views using Android Studio.

I see that you are using `px` units, you should always use `dp` units for everything except text sizes where you should use `sp` units.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.  I'm afraid its all a mystery to me and reading the documentation is akin to reading Egyptian hieroglyphics, I just don't understand the layout system, it wouldn't matter what development platform I used Visual Studio or Android Studio.  I'll take a look at the `ConstraintLayout,`, thanks again.